Metamorphosis of music
I am trying to find a model for transforming one set of data into a second set. Specifically I am interested in is to be able to make a metamorphosis from a piece of music into a second piece, but it could be more generally considered, so any smooth transition-model is very welcome!
Can any one make some suggestions if there are such models?

Can you clarify what you mean by "metamorphosis from a piece of music into a second piece"? It might be a good idea to provide an example of this transformation you're looking for. Also, please, change the title to ask your specific question.

What I basically want to do, is to have a smooth transition of a set of data to another (possibly very different both quantitative and qualitative) set of data. In graphics for instance, there is the famous video-clip of Micheal Jackson's Black or White, at the end where the faces are changed into each other, which was done using the "Feature based Image Methamorphosis" of Beier & co. I am looking if an AI-Model could do that. With an abstract set of data, which could be music or image.
